# Mantener datos del formulario al crear dinamicamente elementos con angular material

Tags: angular5, angular7, angular6

el problema es el siguiente, creo elementos dinamicos con angular y genero el siguiente formulario:

```
<form [formGroup]="dotacionForm" (ngSubmit)="guardarDotacion()"> <p>Dotaciones</p> <div class="form-group" formArrayName="dotaciones"> <div class="form-item" *ngFor="let dotacion of dotaciones.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i"> <mat-form-field fxFlex="30"> <input type="text" matInput formControlName="nombre" [matAutocomplete]="auto"> <mat-error>El valor es requerido</mat-error> <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete"> <mat-option *ngFor="let material of filtroMateriales[i] | async" (click) = "obtenerDatosMaterial(material.n_id,material.cantidad)" [value]="material.v_nombre_material"> {{material.v_nombre_material}} </mat-option> </mat-autocomplete> </mat-form-field> <mat-form-field fxFlex="15" class="pl-4"> <input matInput placeholder="Stock" formControlName="stock" [value]="stock_actual"> </mat-form-field> <mat-form-field fxFlex="15" class="pl-4"> <mat-label>Tipo</mat-label> <mat-select formControlName = "n_id_tipo_dotacion"> <mat-option *ngFor="let ti of tipo" [value]="ti"> {{ti.v_descripcion}} </mat-option> </mat-select> </mat-form-field> <mat-form-field fxFlex="15" class="pl-4"> <mat-label>Obs</mat-label> <mat-select formControlName = "n_id_obs"> <mat-option *ngFor="let ob of obs" [value]="ob"> {{ob.v_nombre}} </mat-option> </mat-select> </mat-form-field> <button (click)="eliminarDotacion(i)" mat-flat-button color="primary">Eliminar</button> </div> </div> <button (click)="agregarNuevaDotacion()" mat-flat-button color="primary">Crear Dotacion</button> <div class="content p-24"> <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="auto auto"> <button mat-raised-button (click)="goBack()">{{cancelButtonText}}</button> <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" tabindex="1">{{confirmButtonText}}</button> </div> </div> </form> obtengo un dato cuando hago click en el input de busqueda, y este devuelve un stock que debo colocar en formControlName="stock" y este no debe modificarse, cuando creo otro elemento se borra el valor y toma el por defecto. El evento .ts es el siguiente: introducir el código aquí obtenerDatosMaterial(id:number,stock:number){ console.log(id,stock); this.id_material = id; this.stock_actual = stock;
```

---

```
   // this.dotaciones.setValue([{"stock": stock, "n_id_material": null, "n_id_talla_material": null, "n_cantidad": null, "n_id_tipo_dotacion": null, "n_id_obs": null } ]);

}
```

gracias saludos

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que tienes declarado el formGroup:

```
private dotacionForm: FormGroup;
```

Asegurate de inicializar los controles con un formBuilder:

```
this.dotacionForm = this.formBuilder.group({
control1: [""],
control2: [""],
...
});
```

Y para settear el valor hazlo así después de inicializar los controles:

```
this.dotacionForm.patchValue({
control1: 'value',
...
});
```